# Copy one Nifti header to another

Tags: matlab, header, nifti

I have a 'prob_map' variable in matlab ( a probability map) which I want to save it in '.nii' format. I did it by 2 lines code:

```
 nii = make_nii(prob_map); 
 save_nii(nii,'prob.nii');
```

This is done successfully however the header info is not compatible with my original CT image named 'img.nii' (hence in ITK-SNAP software the overlaying of prob_map on image is not possible). I want to copy img.nii's header to 'prob.nii' header before saving it. In fact I want to copy one's header as long as it is possible. for example the header size can not be copied while the orientation and other info can be copied.
Is there any function which would copy one's header to another before saving nii? which info have to be copied to keep both nii in same?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [spm matlab library](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPM/Programming_intro#Reading_image_headers_and_data)

```
# Grab header from an existing file (and optionally, get the data)
HeaderInfo  = spm_vol('img.nii')          # use spm_vol to read file header
NiftiData   = spm_read_vol(HeaderInfo)    # use spm_read_vol to get data

# Update the header contents to correspond with your new data
HeaderInfo.fname = 'prob.nii';
HeaderInfo.private.dat.fname = HeaderInfo.fname;

# Save the file with the adapted Header
spm_write_vol(HeaderInfo,Data);           # where Data is your image array
```